# Appium inspector session is very slow (and hanging) when running a session on iOS real device

Tags: ios, iphone, automation, appium-ios, xcuitest

**Scenario**

I'm trying to run automated tests on an iOS real device, however, every time I start the Appium inspector session the client displays the app's loading page and never refreshes to update the inspector and display the home page.

**Problem**

When I manually press the refresh button on Appium the spinner gets displayed and takes a very long time to refresh the inspector. This happens on every interaction with the app.

**Given**

- iOS real device: iPhone 12
- iOS version: 15.1.1
- Appium client: 1.15.0 and then tried 1.17.0

**Capabilities Used**

{
"platformName": "iOS",
"platformVersion": "15.1.1",
"deviceName": "iPhone 12",
"automationName": "XCUITest",
"autoAcceptAlerts": "true",
"bundleId": "com.xxxxx.xxxxx",
"xcodeOrgId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
"updatedWDABundleId": "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner",
"app": "/{path-to-ipaFile}/appFile.ipa",
"udid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

**WebDriverAgent**

Please note that the WebDriverAgent app is trusted (General -> VPN & Device Management).

You can find the logs [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zWXajdp38P6NpXNY5s97EV_jREEhLEpu/view?usp=sharing).

**Appium Server Logs**

You can find the logs [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L5RhsIaorKBycAl4osa8kK4BE7DPf4Fd/view?usp=sharing).

**Failed Attempts for a Solution**

- Add to the capabilities "simpleIsVisibleCheck": "true" and "useJSONSource": "true"
- Add to t he capabilities usePrebuiltWDA=true and derivedDataPath=/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent- ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu/
- Run  Appium server from CLI instead of Appium client

Unfortunately, none of the attempts worked.

**NOTE:** The same problem is occurring on simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the getSession() function in Appium was taking too long to get a response due to a large table list, when I removed the items from the list Appium was fast again and getSession() was not taking a long time to get a response.